# Finding the Bogoliubov- De Gennes Hamiltonian of Pauli Matrices

Tags: condensed-matter, majorana-fermions

I'm studying a book about Majorana Fermions and condensed matter and I'm stuck with an exercise about finding the BdG Hamiltonian of some Hamiltonians in $p$ dependence and Pauli Matrices. I know how to calculate the BdG in case of fermionic/bosonic creation and destruction operators but this is giving me a little bit of confusion.

Example of an Hamiltonian to calculate (but my question is general):

$$H(p)=k  \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{\sigma}$$

Where $\sigma$ is the vector of Pauli Matrices.

Comment: Can you provide more details on what the actual question is?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What I'm trying to ask is how should I get a Bogoliubov- De Gennes Hamiltonian from a Bloch Hamiltonian that contains Pauli Matrices and $p$. Like how should I find it in practice, for example starting with the one that I wrote.

Comment: Usually in this notation there's an implicit vector $\Psi$ of creation/annihilation operators such that the second-quantized Hamiltonian becomes $\mathcal{H}=\Psi^\dagger H\Psi$. Probably that $\Psi$ is stated somewhere in the book you're using.